# Target specific set of CSS classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two instances of elements in my document. One is with just a class of `slide` and the other with a class of `slide` and `slide--current`. Below is an example of this markup.

```
<div class="slide slide--current">
  <h2 class="title title--centered title--modifier">Slide 1</h2>
  <div class="text-block">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide">
  <h2 class="title title--centered title--modifier">Slide 2</h2>
  <div class="text-block">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I want to target `text-block` when it has `slide--current` as the parent I would use `.slide--current > .text-block` as my selector. **But what if I want to target `text-block` when it doesn't have `slide--current`?** I'm asking because both elements need to have the class `slide` applied to them at all times. If I use `.slide .text-block` styles will be applied to `slide--current` when they shouldn't be. Is this a case foe the `:not()` selector?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a pseudo-selector:

```
.slide:not(.slide--current) {
    // styling here
}
```

In your case, as long as .text-block is always a direct child of .slide:

```
.slide > .text-block {
    // Apply to all text blocks regardless of state of slide
}

.slide:not(.slide--current) > .text-block {
    // Only applied if parent slide is not current
}
```

You could probably achieve the same result by reading the answer by @Rounin and avoid pseudo-selectors by reversing your thought process and setting some base styles for all text-blocks first then overriding them when the slide is current.

Comment: would it be `.slide:not(.slide--current) > .text-block` in my case?

Comment: If the text-block is always an immediate child of the slide, sure, I'm just illustrating the use of the pseudo-selector :)

Answer (score 0):

> But what if I want to target `text-block` when it doesn't have
>   `slide--current`?

This is a lesson in how to use the cascade in CSS in the right order.

```
.text-block {

BASIC .text-block STYLES

}

.slide .text-block {

ADDITIONAL .slide .text-block STYLES

}

.slide--current .text-block {

ADDITIONAL .slide--current .text-block STYLES

}
```

Basically, you start with the core styles and you add, cumulatively, as the context grows increasingly specific.